# Java апплет

Tags: applet, javascript, java

Добрый день! дали следующее тестовое задание на работе: Требуется создать java апплет со свойствами:

- Апплет предназначен для запуска с html страницы (в том числе не должно быть препятствий для использования на защищенных страницах - https)/
- у апплета не должно быть видимой части на странице.
- доступ к функциям апплета с помощью javascript с html страницы.
- апплет должен предоставлять браузеру функцию readDir (string pDir) для перечисления файлов и папок по указанному пути с **локального компьютера пользователя** в качестве входного параметра функции.
- Если входной параметр функции передан в апплет пустой строкой, то следует вернуть список элементов из папки "Мой компьютер" (список съемных и несъемных носителей).
- функция readDir возвращает объект, у которого есть две функции: getCount() и getItem(number).
- getCount() возвращает кол-во элементов найденных в папке.
- getItem(number) - возвращает элемент с номером number.
- функция getItem должна возвращать объект содержащий  сведения о: имени файла, типе файла (папка, диск или файл), размере файла в байтах, дате создания, дате изменения. Для получения каждого значения из объекта - отдельная функция.

**Итого:** в программе 2 объекта (класса) и 8 функций. Используйте только стандартные функции, включенные в состав jdk и jre 1.6.x-1.7.x. Доп.библиотеки только при крайней необходимости.

Используйте средство разработки eclipse для java. (желательно)
У нас для компиляции апплета используется плагин maven для eclipse. Возможно, есть альтернатива, изучайте, выбирайте.
Для тестирования работы апплета вам скорее всего потребуется поставить локально denwer или другой пакет веб разработки. 
Для работы апплета без появления предупреждений безопасности, апплет следует подписывать сертификатом, игнорируйте предупреждения безопасности или найдите способ выпустить самоподписанный сертификат на своем компьютере и подписать им апплет после компиляции (на ваш выбор).

В результате у вас должно быть:

1. html страница (test.html) - На странице можно ввести путь к директории на диске, нажать кнопку "получить" и список файлов и папок указанной директории должен отобразиться на странице в виде простой таблицы.
2. скомпилированный апплет (test.jar)
3. папка с исходными кодами апплета.

---

После прочтения этого задания у меня возникли следующие вопросы, так как я совсем не знаю ни javascript, ни java:

- Это задание должно выполняться все-таки на java или на javascript?
- jdk и jre 1.6x-1.7.x входит в состав denwer или я чего-то не понимаю, где это все компилировать код?
- Если компиляция происходит в eclipse, то при установке eclipse нужно ставить еще отдельно jdk и jre?
- Как подключать апплеты к html-страницам, привязывать к событиям кнопки "получить"?
- Как подписывать апплет сертификатом?

Надеюсь мне кто-нибудь поможет ответить на вопрос... Заранее спасибо, друзья.

Comment: Еще появились вопросы. Что за плагин maven? Используется ли он по умолчанию в eclipse? И еще вопрос: Есть ли исходники или примеры, как работают с файлами и каталогами, чтобы их просмотреть?

Answer (score 4):

1. Сам апплет пишется на `Java`, а из `javascript` можно добраться до функции апплета.
2. Если используете среду разработки `Eclipse`, то надо ставить `jdk`, при использовании среды разработки `NetBeans` есть возможность установить и среду и `jdk` "из коробки"
3. Апплет встраивается примерно так

   ```
   <applet code="класса_апплета"> </applet>
   ```
4. На счет подписи апплета в интернете есть подробные инструкции, например здесь - [Подписи в аплетах - как это делается ?](http://forum.vingrad.ru/faq/topic-157929.html)

Comment: спасибо за ответ! А <applet code="класс_апплета"> </applet> это такой html-тег? Если конкретно привязки к кнопке события, как сделать вызов функции readDir?

Comment: так как у вас не должно быть видимой части апплета, то взаимодействие будет через javascript , но для этого в апплете должен быть объект JSObject.

Comment: И если пишется через тег <applet> то где тут применение javascript?

Comment: <applet></applet> это html-тег) 
все взаимодействие между апплетом и браузером/пользователем , в вашем случае, будет через JSObject , который должен быть в апплете.

Comment: А как подключать JSObject к апплету? вроде того: import java.applet.jsobject;?

Comment: Насколько я помню сам JSObject скачивается, потом добовляется к проекту в Eclipse а потом с помощью import в апплет) 
Почитайте информацию по ссылкам

http://javatutor.net/articles/using-jsobject-in-applets
http://spec-zone.ru/RU/Java/Docs/7/technotes/guides/plugin/developer_guide/java_js.html